# Why does Stata return “unknown function +inrange()”?

Tags: stata, local, stata-macros

I am studying Stata programming with the book *An Introduction to Stata Programming, Second Edition*.

In chapter 4 there is code to `generate` a variable that tests whether some other variables satisfy a logical condition, the code is like:

```
foreach v of varlist child1-child12{
        local n_school "`n_school' + inrange(`v', 1, 5)"
    }
    gen n_school = `n_school'
```

When I change this code  to suit my own data,

```
foreach v of varlist qp605_s_1-qp605_s_5 {
        local n_med  "`n_med' + inrange(`v', 1, 5)"
    }
    gen n_med = `n_med'
```

where `qp605_s_1`'s values range from 1 to 17, then Stata returns:

```
. foreach v of varlist qp605_s_1-qp605_s_5 {
  2.         local n_med "`n_med' + inrange(`v', 1, 5)"
  3. }

. gen n_med = `n_med'
unknown function +inrange()
r(133);
```

Any ideas what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input float(var1 var2)
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
end

gen wanted = .

mata :

data = st_data(., "var*")

st_store(., "wanted", rowsum(data :>= 1 :& data :<= 5))

end

list

     +----------------------+
     | var1   var2   wanted |
     |----------------------|
  1. |    1      5        2 |
  2. |    2      6        1 |
  3. |    3      7        1 |
  4. |    4      8        1 |
     +----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I see where I was wrong

The local `n_med` begins with `+`, so I change it to:

```
local n_med 0
foreach v of varlist qp605_s_1-qp605_s_5{
    local n_med "`n_med' + inrange(`v', 1, 5)"
}
gen n_med = `n_med',after(qp605_s_5)
```

and it works!

BTW, according to *An Introduction to Stata Programming*, this method is faster than if you first `generate` a variable which is all zero and then `replace` it by a loop, because the `replace` command is slower than `generate`, so it is better to avoid `replace`.